# System of nonhomogenous differential equations - Undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am taking a course in differential equations and the book I am using is "Elementary Differential Equations" - E. Boyce & R. DiPrima (tenth edition).

My question is about guessing the form of a particular solution to a non-homogeneous system of equations. 
Given a non-homogeneous system of differential equations on the form: $x^{\prime} = Px + g(t)$ where $P$ is a constant $n\times n$ - matrix and $g(t)$ is a continuous vector-function for $α \lt t \lt β$.

Let $υ, ν,$ and $\rho $ be $n\times 1$ - vectors.

On page 442 it is said:

> The procedure for choosing the form of the solution is substantially
>   the same as that given in Section 3.5 for linear second order
>   equations. The main difference is illustrated by the case of a
>   non-homogeneous term of the form $υe^{\lambda t}$ , where $\lambda$ is
>   a simple root of the characteristic equation. In this situation,
>   rather than assuming a solution of of the form $νte^{\lambda t}$ , it
>   is necessary to use $νte^{\lambda t} + \rho e^{\lambda t}$ , where $ν$
>   and $ρ$ are determined by substituting into the differential equation.

My question: How did they come up with $νte^{\lambda t} + \rho e^{\lambda t}$ ? I can not see why it  is necessary for systems to guess that a particular solution (in this case) is a sum. Why is it not enough to just guess that the particular solution will be on the form $νte^{\lambda t}$?

Hope someone can help me to understand this!

Answer (score 0):

For a scalar differential equation with differential operator $L$, the homogeneous equation is $Lx=0$, so if $Le^{\lambda t}=0$, then $L(\rho e^{\lambda t})=0$ as well.

For the matrix case, the homogeneous equation is $L\vec x=\vec0$, so now if you can find an eigenvalue $\lambda$ and an eigenvector $\vec v$ such that $L\vec ve^{\lambda t}=\vec0$, it's not necessarily true that $L\vec ue^{\lambda t}=\vec0$ for any arbitrary constant vector $\vec u$, only for multiples of that eigenvector $\vec v$. Since $\vec ue^{\lambda t}$ doesn't get wiped out by that differential operator the way $\rho e^{\lambda t}$ did in the scalar case, we will have to consider it in our solution.